# Why alloc return nil? ( Objective-C )

Tags: objective-c, null, dynamic-library, alloc

I am porting iOS opengl games to metal

Use metalangle
https://github.com/kakashidinho/metalangle

I use pre-compiled dynamic library

Return nil when creating MGLContext

```
MGLContext * aaa = [MGLContext alloc];

aaa == nil
```

Why is that?

I thought alloc would return nil only when the memory overflowed

Comment: Is it nil on both device and simulator ?

Comment: What returns `[MGLContext class]`?

Answer (score 1):

In modern ObjC, [it is not well-defined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571958-alloc?language=objc#) to only call `+alloc` without then calling an init method:

> You must use an init... method to complete the initialization process. For example:
>
> ```
> TheClass *newObject = [[TheClass alloc] init];
> ```

It was never a good practice, but you now cannot split up allocation and initialization.

That said, how are you testing this? I haven't been able to reproduce it so far. It is possible that `MGLContext` itself is `nil`. That would happen if the dynamic library is [weakly linked](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html), and not present.

Comment: Agree, I simplified the question

The original code is

MGLContext * context = [[MGLContext alloc] init];

And I replaced MGLContext with NSString, aaa is not nil
NSString* aaa= [NSString alloc];

aaa != nil

Comment: `init` is not the designated initializer for `MGLContext`, and is not a convenience initializer either. It requires `initWithAPI:` according to the source code. (I'd still suspect that `MGLContext` is nil because of weak linking, though)

Comment: @opencai so if original code was  `[[MGLContext alloc] init]` then it's more likely that `nil` is returned by `init`, because it's wrong initializer.

Comment: Being the wrong initializer wouldn't return `nil`. It's just not going to correctly setup the object (looking at the code, to see what it actually does). `nil` suggests that something the class isn't available.

Comment: @RobNapier may be there is code: `- (instancetype) init { [super init]; return nil; }`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH; that's what I looked for. Unless it's well hidden, I don't see it in the linked source. Do you?

Comment: @RobNapier  Yes, this is a problem caused by a "weakly linked"
I have solved
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem caused by a "weakly linked"

Thanks @RobNapier

Thank you all

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1xis.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XHBf.jpg)